# Ionic event not triggered when app goes in background (plattform pause)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to perform some actions when my app goes to the background—e.g., when pressing the home button. (I am testing on an Android device.)

I tried the following in my `app.component.ts`:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(async () => {
      alert("Pause event detected"); 
      //Do stuff here
    });

    this.platform.resume.subscribe(async () => {
      alert("Resume event detected");
      //Do stuff here
    });
…
```

I also tried:

```
App.getState().then((result) => {
  alert("state active?" + result.isActive);
});
```

No listener is triggered when the app goes to background (e.g., by pressing the home button). But when I start the app again, all events are triggered (in this case, the alerts), including the `platform.pause` event.

I am using Ionic 9 and Capacitor.

Am I misunderstanding something? What could be the problem?

Comment: did u mean Angular 9 and Ionic 5 ?

Comment: Sorry... ionic 5, of cource.

Comment: There's a warning not to use blocking functions such as alert inside these events. Are you sure that wasn't the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... things work. The problem was, that I had both variants in code active.

Comment: Really? That doesn't seem like it should be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunetly it was.

Comment: I have them both working on the same page just find in Android but only the AppState one works on iOs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the event listeners provided in [Capacitor's App API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/app).

```
// Import the relevant stuff from Capacitor
import { Plugins, AppState } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;
```

Then in your AppComponent class

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    App.addListener('appStateChange', (state: AppState) => {
        if (state.isActive) {
            console.log('App has become active');
        } else {
            console.log('App has become inactive');
        }
    });

})
```

Note that you can test this in a desktop browser as well by switching to another tab.